# File .htaccess disappears

Tags: nautilus, hidden-files, .htaccess

I installed ubuntu and want to put my Web script (php) what happens when I put the files via USB is the USB .htaccess disappears. Someone could help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to hide hidden files / folders from nautilus broswer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/516264/not-able-to-hide-hidden-files-folders-from-nautilus-broswer)

Comment: additional info: http://askubuntu.com/a/116824/354350

Answer (score 5):

When a `.file` has a dot before his name, that means it is hidden -> [The long story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory)

To display it on nautilus, you can try the shortcut `ctrl + H`

If you are on console, try `ls -a`

Comment: In Nautilus and nemo this is an option in the View menu!

Comment: Sorry but I'm new to ubuntu , so would that be ? Thank you.